# Where does the group $\mathbb Z/(a)\oplus \mathbb Z/(a^2)\oplus \cdots $ arise?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, geometric-series

Let $a>1$ be an integer, and consider the infinite abelian group
$$
V_a=\bigoplus_{j=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z/{a^j\mathbb Z}.
$$

Can anyone provide references to places where this (or related) groups arise in the literature? The groups $V_4$ and $V_8$ have recently cropped up in a problem I am working on.

Comment: The product is often used in defining the $a$-adic integers (the $a$-adic integers  are a subring/subgroup of the product.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the notation here is the algebraic direct sum not the product. Does that not usually mean that all but finitely many entries of any element are $0$?

Comment: I realize that. @Mathmo123 The question asked for "or related groups."

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319946/is-mathbbz-p-mathbbn-mathbbz-widely-studied-does-it-have-an-accepted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this group does not naturally appear anywhere.

A closely related group is the ["Prufer $a$-group"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) (in quotes because it is usually only defined for $a$ a prime), which is a certain quotient of this group. Its Pontryagin dual is the ["$a$-adic integers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) (again, in quotes because it is usually only defined for $a$ a prime), which is a certain subgroup of the corresponding infinite product. Both of these groups show up in various places.