# Profinite completion of integers, $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, is isomorphic to the product over primes of the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups

I've been trying to show that the profinite completion of the integers, $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic to the product over $p$ of the $p$-adic integers. But I'm kind of stuck. Here is what I got so far.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have $$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\simeq \underset{p}\prod \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}$$ hence $$\underset{n}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\simeq \underset{n}\varprojlim\underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}$$ where the inverse limit on the right is taken with respect to the projections, for $m|n$:$$\underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow\underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$$ $$(x_p+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z})_p\mapsto x+n\mathbb{Z}\mapsto x+m\mathbb{Z}\mapsto (x+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z})_p$$ where $x+n\mathbb{Z}$ is the unique element in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}=x_p+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}$. We now define the map $$\underset{n}\varprojlim\underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \underset{p}\prod\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\ ,\ \{(x_{n,p}+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z})_p\}_n\mapsto(\{x_{m,p}+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\}_m)_p$$Where inverse limit on the right is taken with repsect to projections, for $k|m$, $\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(k)}\mathbb{Z}$ . The map clearly does not depend on coset representatives and after messing around for a bit we can show that indeed for fixed $p$, $\{x_{m,p}+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\}_m$ is an element of $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$. Hence the map is well defined and it's clearly a bijective ring homomorphism hence an isomorphism.

Now it remains to show that for fixed $p$ we have $$\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\simeq\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$$ **This is where I am having problems.** The orderings on $m$ are not compatible and I haven't been able to construct a well defined map so far. I also thought of constructing a chain of isomorphisms $$\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\simeq\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m!)}\mathbb{Z}\simeq\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$$ to try and make the orderings on $m$ align a bit better but haven't had any luck in defining suitable maps. **Note that I am not looking for categorical proofs regarding the isomorphism in question. I've already been through some of those. I am looking for hints on construcing explicit maps**

**Edit after Eric Wofsey's response**: We define the ring homomorphism$$\theta:\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\underset{r}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}\ ,\ (x_m+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z})_m\mapsto (x_{p^r}+p^r\mathbb{Z})_r$$ This is well defined by construction since $p^r|p^{r+1}$ hence by the inverse system of $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$ we have that $x_{p^{r+1}}+(p^{v_p(p^r)}=p^r)\mathbb{Z}=x_{p^r}+(p^{v_p(p^r)}=p^r)\mathbb{Z}$ which is exactly what is required for $(x_{p^r}+p^r\mathbb{Z})_r$ to be an element of $\underset{r}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$. Now let $x:=(x_m+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z})_m\in ker(\theta)$ then $x_{p^r}\in p^r\mathbb{Z}, \forall r\geq 1$. Now if $p\nmid m$, $v_p(m)=0$ hence $x_m\in p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$. If $p|m$ then $v_p(m)=r$ for some $r\geq1$. Then since $p^r|m$ we have by the inverse system of $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$ that $x_m+p^{v_p(p^r)}\mathbb{Z}=x_{p^r}+p^{v_p(p^r)}\mathbb{Z}=0+p^r\mathbb{Z}$ Hence $x_m\in p^r\mathbb{Z}=p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $x=0$ in $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$, hence $\theta$ injects.

Now given an element $y:=(y_r+p^r\mathbb{Z})_r\in\underset{r}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$, we consider the element $x:=(x_m+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z})_m\in\underset{m}\prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$ where $$x_m:=y_{v_p(m)},\ \text{if}\ v_p(m)\geq 1$$ $$x_m:=0,\ \text{if}\ v_p(m)=0$$ Now take $n|m$ then if $p\nmid n$ we have that $x_m+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}=x_m+\mathbb{Z}=0+\mathbb{Z}=x_n+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}$. So assume $p|n$ hence $p|m$ which implies that $x_m=y_{v_p(m)}\ ,\ x_n=y_{v_p(n)}$. Then by the inverse system of $\underset{r}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ we have that $x_m+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}=y_{v_p(m)}+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}=y_{v_p(n)}+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}=x_n+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}$ Hence indeed we have that the element $x$ belongs in $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$ and furthermore, it maps to $y$ under $\theta$. Hence $\theta$ also surjects and we have an isomorphism. So overall we have shown that $$\hat{\mathbb{Z}}=\underset{n}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow\underset{n}\varprojlim\ \underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow\underset{p}\prod\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow\underset{p}\prod\underset{r}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}=\underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}_p$$ $$\{x_n+n\mathbb{Z}\}_n\mapsto \{(x_n+p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z})_p\}_n\mapsto (\{x_m+p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\}_m)_p\mapsto (\{x_{p^r}+p^r\mathbb{Z}\}_r)_p$$
**Hence we end up with the isomorphism** $$\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow\underset{p}\prod\mathbb{Z}_p$$ $$\{x_n+n\mathbb{Z}\}_n\mapsto (\{x_{p^r}+p^r\mathbb{Z}\}_r)_p$$

Comment: Please note that math-only titles are discouraged. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233) for more information.

Comment: It is obvious that the map $\prod_p \Bbb{Z}_p \to \varprojlim_{n\to \infty} \prod\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(n)}\mathbb{Z}$ is injective and surjective

Comment: It would be better to post your solution as an answer rather than editing it into the question, since it is an answer to the question rather than part of the question itself.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256732/96384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be getting yourself confused by using the same index variable $m$ on both sides.  As you say, these $m$'s are given two totally different orderings, so you shouldn't think of them as corresponding.  So let's call one of them $n$, so we're looking for an isomorphism $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\simeq\underset{n}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

Now there's an obvious way you might try to get a map between these: just have the terms $\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$ where $v_p(m)=n$ correspond to the term $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.   For instance, if you restrict $m$ to just take values in the powers of $p$, you get that the inverse system of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$'s is a subsystem of the inverse system of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$'s.  This gives you a projection map $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}\to\underset{n}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ which just omits all the coordinates corresponding to values of $m$ which are not powers of $p$.  Now you just have to check that this map really is an isomorphism.  This amounts to checking that an element of $\underset{m}\varprojlim\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{v_p(m)}\mathbb{Z}$ is uniquely determined by its values on coordinates where $m$ is a power of $p$ (so the map is injective), and that if you choose those values in a compatible way you can always extend to all other values of $m$ in a compatible way (so the map is surjective).

Comment: Ok thank you, this has been very usefull! I'll now try to to write everything down in detail.

Comment: No idea why this has gotten two downvotes.  Is there something wrong in the answer?